# Understanding root access better

Tags: permissions, root

I'm attempting to save a .sh file to usr/share/blueproximity and I'm being told that I don't have sufficient permissions. sudo id says uid is 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new at Linux, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's `usr/share/bluproximity`? That directory path starts in your current directory and probably doesn't exist. I'll continue using `/usr/share/blueproximity`.

`sudo id` runs the `id` command (see `man id`) as another user, `root` in this case (see `man sudo`). When (`root`) `id` exits, `sudo` exits, too.

Here are two ways of doing what you're asking:

```
sudo cp file.sh /usr/share/blueproximity
```

or

```
cat file.sh | sudo tee /usr/share/blueproximity/file.sh
```

In either case, you'l have to concern yourself with the permissions and ownership of `/usr/share/blueproximity/file.sh`.

However, the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard( [Linux FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) ) says

```
/usr/share : Architecture-independent data
```

so I question your adding your script there. Are you sure? Reread `man blueproximity`, look at `dpkg -L blueproximity` for other files to read.

If you have `git` installed, you can `git clone https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git`, and use `pathlld /usr/share/blueproximity` to look at permissions. Also read `pathlld` - it's a Bash script.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I'm going to go figure out the answers to your questions and play around with your suggestions. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I round out the reason why, this computer is on my company's network so I assume they have the ultimate say in what I can access and what I can't despite being 'root'. Any comment? Thanks again.

Comment: when I attempted to purge blueproximity one of the last things the terminal displays is:   "Purging configuration files for blueproximity (1.2.5-6)...dpkg:warning: while removing blueproximity, directory 'usr/share/blueproximity not empty so not removed"

Comment: @Niko_Jako Since you're desparate, and are trying to uninstall `blueproximity`, I will reccommend, ***in this case only***, using the Big Gun, and doing `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/blueproximity`, unless you want to investigate it first.

Comment: haha I just rushed back on to tell you that's what I figured out. Thank you so much for your prompt responses and help!